# d3js set tickValues for time scale axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've searched in the official d3.js documentation, as well as, here in stackoverflow to find a way to add custom tickValues to a time scale axis; However, i haven't stumble across any documentation that confirms that something like that is possible.

So in essence, i have a time scale axis and i would like to show specific hours
e.g. i'd like to do something like this :

```
xHourAxis
   .ticks(d3.time.hours, 2)
   .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
   .tickValues(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12) ;
```

So i want to display tick values every 2 hours, but not including the first (12 am) and the last (12 pm).

Does anyone know if there is any workaround for that?

Comment: Don't specify `ticks()` if you also use `tickValues()`. The tick values you specify need to be time values, but apart from that it should work. How is it not working for you?

Comment: It just doesn't display any ticks for the value i pass; even though i got rid of ticks()

Comment: As I've said, you need to pass date objects and not just integers.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there, but your code has two problems: First the tick values must be specified in an array, and second those values should be Javascript date objects. i.e. you just provide an array of dates to `tickValues` so your code would looks something like this:

```
xHourAxis
 .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
 .tickValues([new Date(2000,10,5), new Date(2005,2,7), new Date(2007,11,11)]);
```

Also, note that you needn't call the `ticks()` if you are going to later specify custom values.